# NativeScript socketio not connecting to server (instance on ioBroker)

Tags: socket.io, connection, nativescript

I'm facing an issue working with NativeScript socketio trying to connect to an instance on ioBroker. 
There is no Error, but no connection is established either. I tried to connect to it in via webapplication and it worked, so there should not be an issue with the server. This is what I did in NativeScript:

I build this Service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as SocketIO from "nativescript-socketio";;
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketService {
  options = {
    query: {
      token: '',
    },
    android: {
      // http://socketio.github.io/socket.io-client-java/apidocs/io/socket/client/IO.Options.html
    },
    ios: {
      // https://nuclearace.github.io/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Enums/SocketIOClientOption.html
    }
  };

 private socketio : SocketIO.SocketIO;

  connectToSocket(): Rx.Subject<MessageEvent>{
    this.socketio = SocketIO.connect('http://192.168.178.50:8085', this.options);
    const observable = new Observable(observer => {
      this.socketio.on('lampe', data => {
        console.log('message from server');
        observer.next(data);
      });
      return () => {
        this.socketio.disconnect();
      };
    });
    const observer = {
      next: (data:Object) => {
        this.socketio.emit('lampe', data);
      }
    };
    return Rx.Subject.create(observer, observable)
  }


  disconnect(){
    this.socketio.disconnect();
  }
}
```

Handler:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SocketService } from './socket.service';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConnHandlerService {

  messages: Subject<any>;

  constructor(private socketService: SocketService) { 
    this.messages = <Subject<any>>this.socketService
    .connectToSocket()
    .map((response: any): any => {
      return response;
    });
  }

  sendmsg(msg){
    this.messages.next(msg);
  }
}
```

Also there is a Button in my Home-Component, that triggers sendmsg() with this.connHandlerService.sendmsg('val:false');

Comment: Did you try testing your server with the demo app comes in plugin repo?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that didn't work either. It works fine in a browser, but as soon as i'm running it on my phone  or an emulator it won't work.

Comment: Did you try the demo server?

Comment: Yes. The same result.

Update from yesterday:
I put in a debug node (serverside) that just logs every message the Socket sends or receives. It seems, the connection is established and canceled right after. Thought I might have made a mistake in connectToSocket(), but it looks fine to me. 

Tank you for helping me out with this.